# Split three integers from text using regex c#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, split

I would like to match any three numbers delimited by comma and can be start and end with brackets.

Valid Examples are:
{30,40,50}, [30,40,50], (30,40,50) or 30,40,50

it possible also 30, 40,50 (means, can be spaces after commas and before one of the three numbers)

Non valid examples are:
{30,40,50 or {30,40,50]

and I would like after to split only the integres.

I tried:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"({|(|[)?\d+,\d+,\d+({|(|[)?");
Match match = regex.Match(laticeDim.Text);
if (match.Success)
{
    int[] integers = laticeDim.Text.Trim('{', '}', '[', ']', '(', ')').Split(',')
        .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s))
        .ToArray();

}
```

But I got run time error on the first code line above.

Any suggestions? What is the best way to match such expression?

Comment: Try [`{(?<val>\d+(?:,\d+){2})}|\[(?<val>\d+(?:,\d+){2})]|\((?<val>\d+(?:,\d+){2})\)|(?<![[({])\b(?<val>\d+(?:,\d+){2})\b(?![])}])`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b\(%3f%3cval%3e%5cd%2b\(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b\)%7b2%7d\)%7d%7c%5c%5b\(%3f%3cval%3e%5cd%2b\(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b\)%7b2%7d\)%5d%7c%5c\(\(%3f%3cval%3e%5cd%2b\(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b\)%7b2%7d\)%5c\)%7c\(%3f%3c!%5b%5b\(%7b%5d\)%5cb\(%3f%3cval%3e%5cd%2b\(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b\)%7b2%7d\)%5cb\(%3f!%5b%5d\)%7d%5d\)&i=+%7b30%2c40%2c50%7d+%5b30%2c40%2c50%5d+\(30%2c40%2c50\)++30%2c40%2c50%0d%0a%7b30%2c40%2c50+or+%7b30%2c40%2c50%5d).Use `match.Groups["val"].Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation of the error

You received an error because you forgot to escape the special chars `(` and `[`. Note that you are also ending your regex looking for *opening* braces (for simplicity I'll call them all `braces`) at the end of your regex (fixed in my answer).

## Regex solution

This regex should be better:`({|\(|\[)?\s*\d+,\s*\d+,\s*\d+\s*(}|\)|\])?`

It's about as complex as yours is (so you should understand it). It's also only slightly longer.

Here's how it works:

```
#Is there an opening brace?
(
    {|\(|\[
)?

#Find the numbers, even with spaces.
    #Note: currently, does not allow spaces between # and comma
\s*
\d+,\s*
\d+,\s*
\d+\s*

#Is there a closing brace?
(
    }|\)|\]
)?
```

## Changes to your C#

My regex will capture both your wanted and unwanted strings, and it will also break your current code (I think, but I don't know C#). Fortunately, it should be easy to fix all these problems.

You can use `.Replace( "regex", "")` with these regexes: `[{}]`, `[\[\]]`, `[)(]` to remove the braces. If you do this in a loop (3 iterations, one per regex), you can compare the original length to the length of the new string. If the difference in length is 1, you found a bad match and you go right to checking the next match. After a match passes all three iterations, `.Split` it on the commas, `.Trim` the whitespace, and finally, add the numbers to your array.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
[{|(|[)?\d+,\d+,\d+(}|)|]]?
```

Comment: Could you explain why/how this regex answers the question please? It will be more helpful to others if it's clear what the difference is.